# Bootstrap form-inline icons on input object not at the end

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to do a online form with validation states and icons, but I want the icon to be on the input and not on the select.

I have a code like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lzfx1rky/2/

```
<form class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <select class="form-control">
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Some way to do this or I just have to put the input on another div and put only there the icon?

Thanks

Comment: the icon is on the input and not on the select, where do you want it to be?

Comment: @Fanax I see it on the select.. you micht see it like that do to size, try enlarging the size of the result or try here http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lzfx1rky/2/show/ you should see both elements in one line

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstraps grid classes for inlining. Your design becomes responsive and you can easily control how big each element is.

```
<form>
<div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <select class="form-control" style="float: left;">
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the result:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzfx1rky/5/)